# python how to change the global variables

Tags: python

I would like to get some kind of confirmation that the upload is success, I have my methods defined similar to the following. However the value of global variable is not changing. Please help

```
global upload_confirm
upload_confirm = False

def confirm_upload():
    upload_confirm = True

def start_new_upload():
    confirm_upload()
    while (upload_confirm != True):
        print "waiting for upload to be true"
        time.sleep(5)
    if (upload_confirm == True):
        print "start Upload"

start_new_upload()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
def confirm_upload():
    global upload_confirm
    upload_confirm = True
```

Since you are doing `upload_confirm = True` in a local scope, Python treat it like a local variable. Hence, your global variable stays the same.

Comment: If I want just to read a global variable, can I skip the `global` declaration at start of each function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `global` statement in that scope where you want to access the global variable, i.e.:

```
upload_confirm = False

def confirm_upload():
    global upload_confirm
    upload_confirm = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your `confirm_upload()` method.

```
def confirm_upload():
    global upload_confirm #Add this line
    upload_confirm = True
```

You need to declare it as global inside methods else it will be by default local.

Answer (score 0):

`global` statement should be inside the function.

```
def confirm_upload():
    global upload_confirm
    upload_confirm = True
```

Otherwise, `upload_confirm = ..` will create a local variable.